# Durandal with latest TypeScript

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript, durandal, single-page-application

At some point, this, **used** to work:

```
import app = module('durandal/app');
```

However since the new import syntax is:

```
import app = durandal/app
```

The above failed miserably to compile. I tried the syntax with a more normal looking namespace convention eg. "Durandal.App" (w/o the quotes) and it'd work. So it seems the slash is throwing the compiler parser off.

Any work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new import syntax is

`import app = require('durandal/app');`

Comment: Does not work on latest type script see specs: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267238. VS2013 definitely doesn't like that syntax either.

Comment: I assure you what Ryan Cavanaugh said is correct. The `module` keyword was changed to `require`.

Comment: I would like to if that were the case, but the syntax gave me red wiggly underline with an error saying: "Expression is not a statement or call". What am I missing? If I use "import app = my.module.class" <-- This works, but the modules in durandal.d.ts file are not in this format.

Comment: Have you read page 122 of the document you linked? You need to post more of the code you're using for us to be able to figure out exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: You're right, I am not sure what's wrong may be my reference path was off or resharper cache got in the way. Seems to be working now.